# SQL query for adding values based on comparison with other rows, cross matching rows

Tags: sql

I need to calculate the total **trading volume** between the same seller and buyer couple. I couldn't find a similar example.

```
|      sales          |      seller      |      buyer      |
|---------------------|------------------|-----------------|               
|      264120         |        101       |       42        | 
|      175887         |         42       |      101        |
```

For example, I need to find the total volume between '101' and '42'. They will be both in the position of sellers and buyers. The first and second rows sales will be summed.

The expected result is the sales sum of each pair in one row:

```
|      sales          | trading_couple1  | trading_couple2 |
|---------------------|------------------|-----------------|               
|      440,007        |        101       |       42        |
```

So how to do this with an SQL query? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please avoid posting [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of data, sample data should be *consumable text* in your question, ideally as *create* and *insert* statements, or alternatively a [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/). See the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: `with data as (select *, case when seller < buyer then seller else buyer end as party1, case from T when seller < buyer then buyer else seller end as party2) select party1, party2, sum(sales) from data group by party1, party2`

Comment: Do you really want `sales` to be double precision?

Comment: Hey thank you for the response and no, it is not a must

Comment: With that table data, what is the expected result?

Comment: The expected result is the sum of each pair in one row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution without using a CTE.

- create and populate the table

```
create table if not exists sale(
sales int,
seller int,
buyer int);
insert into sale values
(264120,101,42),
(175887,42,101),
(20,1,2),
(30,1,2),
(40,2,1);
```

- and the query

```
SELECT SUM(SALES) sales,
CASE WHEN seller<buyer THEN CONCAT(seller,"-",buyer) ELSE CONCAT(buyer,"-",seller) END partners
FROM sale
GROUP BY
CASE WHEN seller<buyer THEN CONCAT(seller,"-",buyer) ELSE CONCAT(buyer,"-",seller) END ;
```

- gives this output

```
sales      partners
90         1-2
444007     42-101
```